# Vuejs : Accessing Specific URL Segment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a route/URL :

> Ex. http://localhost:8080/qr-codes

I want to access to the first segment

`qr-codes`

How do I do that ?

I used to be able to do sth like this in Laravel

> Request::segment(1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`URL.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
const str = 'http://localhost:8080/qr-codes';

const firstSegment = (new URL(str)).pathname.split('/')[1];

console.log(firstSegment);
```

Vue demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    path: function() {
      const firstSegment = (new URL(window.location.href)).pathname.split('/')[1];
      return `${firstSegment}/create`;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{path}}</div>
```

Comment: Is there a one-line way ? I will just prepend this to my create button.

Comment: Ex. /qr-codes/create

Comment: The first segment need to be dynamic ... I am passing that in as a prob.

Comment: @code8888 you can group them as above.

Comment: I don't know how to do that can call it. I'm new to Vue.js. Can you show in a form of .vue ? Like use that code in the script tag and call in the template tag ?

Comment: Can you provide more context on what you're trying to do?

Comment: base on the current URL, the create button will be dynamically  `/$segment1/create`

Comment: If the current url is : /cats the create button will be /cats/create

Comment: You can look into computed properties where you define a property that would return the first segment of ``window.location.href`` as above concatenated with ``/create`` in the end

Comment: Can you please update your answer in a Vue.js form ? Your answer is purely JS.

Comment: I've tried computed:, mounted:, but I kept running into errors due to syntax

Comment: @code8888 answer updated

Comment: I noticed a bug, where it ran twice. See : `http://localhost:8080/qr-codes/qr-codes/create`

Comment: What do you mean by "ran twice"?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const getUrlPathSegments = () => (
  (new URL(window.location.href)).pathname.split('/').filter(Boolean)
)
```

for example, when you call the function on current stackoverflow page, you get:

```
getUrlPathSegments() === ['questions', '70427242', 'vuejs-accessing-specific-url-segment']

getUrlPathSegments()[0] === 'questions'
```